# when you click on the function button (start) is not implemented

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop

```js
<script>
var imgsrc = [];
for (i=0;i<30;i++)
    imgsrc[i] = "images/"+i+".jpg";
function start() {
  $numberimg = document.getElementById("numberimg").value;
  $numbercolumn = document.getElementById("numbercolumn").value;
  for (i = 0; i < $numberimg; i++) {
    text += "<img src='" + imgsrc[i] + "'><br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
 margin:0px;
 font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 background-color:#B800FF;
}
.wrapper{
 width:100%;
 margin:0px;}
.container{
 width:960px;
 margin:auto;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;}
#select{
 margin-bottom:50px;
 margin-top:50px;}
.selection{
 width:195px;
 font-size:17px;
 margin-left:30px;
 border:#000000 solid 2px;}
#content{
 background-color:#BD2C2F;
 margin-top:50px;
 height:200px;
 width:100%;
 margin:0px;}
#content div {
 margin:10px;
 box-sizing:border-box;}
</style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div id="select">
 <form>
  <select id="numberimg" class="selection" title="select a number">
          <option value="-1">insert number image</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
        </select> 
        <select id="numbercolumn" class="selection" title="select a number">
          <option value="-1">insert number column </option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select> 
        <button onClick="start()">go</button>
 </form>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When a function is deleted from the javascript code to work correctly, but does not run with the function codes

Comment: Where do you defined `text`?

Comment: Not working in a fiddle?

Comment: Problem 1 - You have to cancel the default form submit action;
Problem 2 - You haven't defined the `text` variable;
Problem 3 - You have to close the `div` you opened `<br/></div>`

Comment: How's it not working?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `text` variable before increment it.

```
 function start() {
     var text = ""; // Initialize it as an empty string
     $numberimg = document.getElementById("numberimg").value;
     $numbercolumn = document.getElementById("numbercolumn").value;
     for (i = 0; i < $numberimg; i++) {
        text += "<div><img src='" + imgsrc[i] + "'><br></div>";
     }
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = text;
 }
```

Take a look at this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/079eLwdg/1/)

Comment: Thank you . But not run again

Comment: It's runing on the FIDDLE. Have you tried to cancel the default form submit action? `onsubmit="return false"`